# A world where people have suddenly lost the ability to count

Tags: society

I'm trying to construct a world where people can only distinguish between three concepts of numeracy - nothing (0), something (1) and everything (2 to infinite).

How will this affect the world, when trading can only be between two objects, age is completely visual and time can no longer be tracked?

Will society still be able to function as a democracy or will the world descend into anarchism?

What will we become without numbers? I would love to hear your thoughts.

Edit: Regarding Tim B's comment - society has suddenly lost the ability to visualize any number above one. People can still tell if any multitude is greater than one, just can't on earth figure out by how much.

Comment: In order for us to answer the question I think you will need to explain how this happens, since any rational world would just re-invent numbers!

Comment: It's not that they have forgotten numbers, they are still very much present in society. It's the fact they have completely lost the ability to use them, due to some sort of tragic event - which I haven't completely nailed down yet.

Comment: Hi welcome to the site are you referring to binary number, a computer fits your description it can only recognize high(usually 1) and low(usually 0) and hangs(RAM reaches max capacity denote big number) but for convenience we developed a higher language to read and write assembly language(binary code).

Comment: @user6760 Hey thanks for the welcome. It's kind of like binary with an extra component, except that it isn't base three, just three numbers, with one number - everything -  allocated all numbers par 1 and 0.

Comment: Everybody dies. Next question!

Comment: @Serban Tanasa ❗

Comment: Keep in mind that 1 (*unit*) could refer to (*multiple*) "other units" - While thinking of what my answer would be I basically decided that numbers would be re-invented - even if they couldn't translate between the different units they would still know they could have one apple. one barrel of apples. one basket of apples. They only need the most-used units to get by.

Comment: So instead of having many numbers for many different units, we can get by with one number and many (*more*) different units.

Comment: Ask these guys. Brazil's Pirahã Tribe: Living without Numbers or Time. The Pirahã people have no history, no descriptive words and no subordinate clauses. That makes their language one of the strangest in the world -- and also one of the most hotly debated by linguists. - http://www.spiegel.de/international/spiegel/brazil-s-piraha-tribe-living-without-numbers-or-time-a-414291.html

Comment: @Tarius - there is an Amazonian tribe called the Pirahå who have [no concept of numbers](http://www.spiegel.de/international/spiegel/brazil-s-piraha-tribe-living-without-numbers-or-time-a-414291.html)

Comment: [Documentary](http://www.smithsonianchannel.com/shows/the-grammar-of-happiness/0/141519) on the Pirahå

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that society collapses and most of the race dies in a few years or less.

In the short term, most of the world depends critically on long-distance motorized transportation. Ensuring that a vehicle has enough fuel is a very arithmetic-sensitive process. As vehicles run out of fuel at inconvenient places, and fuel distribution breaks down, chaos begins. Furthermore, running an oil refinery is also done by numbers, so pretty soon the refineries will start catching fire due to faulty pressure regulation in critical parts. And let's not think too hard what happens to nuclear plants when temperatures start to rise in the core.

In the medium term, agriculture depends on mostly on the production of annual crops. These crops require the setting aside of seed from the year's harvest. Being unable to tell how much to set aside will result either in wastage due to too much seed/too little consumption or too little seed and too-small a crop the next year. While this is not strictly true for modern hybrid crops, the process of producing those hybrids does need the sort of control that only numbers produce. Additionally, the application of pesticides and fertilizers must be controlled numerically.

More fundamentally, any economic system above the level of barter is intrinsically dependent on numbers and the ability to do arithmetic at a level above "0/1/many". And even barter gets into trouble above the "I'll give you a tomato for an apple" level. The entire question of "How many" becomes unworkable when there is only "many".

Comment: I agree with most of this, but according to the thermometer in the nuclear plant's core, the temperature is still 2 degrees. What do you mean it's going up? ;)

Comment: @Frostfyre - Do you mean the "2" degrees with 1 digit, or the "2" degrees with 2 digits?

Comment: The OP mentioned 2 as being everything above 1.

Comment: @Frostfyre - Actually, it says "everything (2 to infinite)".

Comment: How many seeds? All of the (*possibly infinite for all we know*) seeds that are in this one barrel. We know the barrel is full because we are unable to add more seeds without getting more barrels, even though we can't count them.

Comment: It was supposed to be a joke. Apparently, my humor didn't translate well through text.